# Do you keep your rewards and score etc when you are kicked from a server?

Tags: battlefield-3

I know that in MechWarrior Online if you quit (or crash, whathaveyou) that any scores or accomplishments you have made in the match will be awarded to you at its conclusion (even though you're not in it).

I was wondering if Battlefield 3 did the same.
Like, it may do so if you quit (so the game has a chance to 'shut down') but what if you crash, are kicked, or otherwise disconnected abruptly?

I don't think it increases your scores (experience etc) whilst the game is running, but I don't know if it will still amend your profile if you aren't there when the match ends (I've logged back into a match before and found my score to be 0 with 0 kills and deaths as if I was never there).

Answer (score 2):

Out of experience i can say that:

- If you unlock a customization on a weapon or vehicle during the game and then get kicked, the unlocked part will come through after the game you were kicked from has ended.
- same for unlocking a weapon, getting a service star with a weapon or vehicle and points towards a class (assault, recon, engineer, support)
- K/D will also be updated on battlelog after the game has ended, even if you rejoin the game and start with 0/0; the previous K/D will also be counted.

however, i don't know if ribbons/medals are counted or saved; and i don't know if you will get points towards your global rank (sergeant, colonel, captain)

Answer (score 1):

From recent experience, I got 7 kills with a shotgun and picked up my first shotgun ribbon.  I was kicked by an admin shortly after because of some no shotgun rule on the rented server.

In the Battlelog website I noticed I didn't have the ribbon.  However, after a few minutes another page refresh showed I had unlocked the ribbon.

Going by other observations with ribbons and weapon kills, I would say that the rewards etc are updated periodically rather than instantly.  That seems pretty much true for games in progress (i.e. get a kill with a gun, then immediately refresh the Battlelog website doesn't increase your kill count for a gun).

I can't say for certain but it does appear that the stats are updated when the game ends.  If you get kicked from a game, you need to wait for the game to end in order to update your stats.

To complicate matters, if you rejoin a server your previous progress is not wiped.  For example, if you get 5 kills, leave, rejoin, and get another 5 kills then your stats will update with 10 kills.  This is the same for ribbons (I got a squad wipe ribbon either side of a rejoin, and my ribbons increased by 2).

I don't know what will happen if the server crashes or is taken down mid-game, my experiences above are through getting kicked by an admin or leaving through the menu.  This also seems to match how both the Medal of Honor games updated servers.

Answer (score -1):

No, it will not save your progress in that game.
I believe, that if you join the exact same server, and finish that round, you will keep your progress.

Comment: For an up-vote/accept; are you able to find references, or say that this happened to you (your exp didn't increase at the conclusion of a match you were kicked from)?

Comment: If it was BF4, I could confirm. It probably is the same in BF3, but I also have no evidence for it.

Answer (score -1):

I held my upgrades after I got kicked. I joined the same server and ended with 6000 score,  it said +12000 so it counted to score from my last game don't how this is if you join another game